# Angular.js - prefill input with one property, but set ng-model to different property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have my input:

```
input(ng-model='amount' ng-init='amount = (amount == 0) ? total : amount')
```

So I need the user-inputted value to be saved to `amount`, however, when the page loads, if `amount` happens to be zero, then prefill it with `total`.

All works fine, however, I have an interval running to refresh the data from the server, so when that refresh happens, I'm guessing the model value `amount` changes, and it sets the input to "0" (if `amount` was zero). How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is with the usage of [`ng-init`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit), first of all it is not appropriate to use it for anything else other than aliasing ng-repeat special properties like `$index`, `$first` etc... ng-init'ed expressions are not watched during every digest cycle for changes. Moreover viewvalue update is done when ng-model is updated. So you do not see it getting evaluated during a later digest cycle. Instead of using `ng-init` just set the `ng-model` itself in the controller to the default value.

```
 $scope.amount = $scope.amount || $scope.total;
```

Or you could as well use [getter setter option of the ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel#binding-to-a-getter-setter).

Answer (score 0):

Create new variable inputAmount, bind it to your input.

```
input(ng-model='inputAmount' ng-init='inputAmount = (amount == 0) ? total : amount')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use optional assignment on you model in controller.

```
$scope.myModel = $scope.myModel || $scope.prefilled
```

I created codeopen example of it: http://codepen.io/skymk/pen/vOyPWB?editors=101